# Ignore call inside batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm having trouble understanding how CALL works in a batch file. Simple enough, but I'm confused.

I want to have a simple batch file that has three calls but only uses two.

```
@ ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
CLS

:HELLO
ECHO Hello

:BANANAS
ECHO Bananas!

:WORLD
ECHO World!
GOTO:EOF

CALL HELLO
CALL WORLD
```

The result I want is:

```
Hello
World!
```

What I get is:

```
Hello
Bananas!
World!
```

Obviously I can just REM out the bananas code that I don't want printing, but that's not what I'm after.

Comment: You probably don not fully understand calling block of code in windows shell scripts, see differences between `GOTO` and `CALL` statements

Comment: A batch-file is processed from top to bottom unless there are commands to tell something else; so there are no real main and sub-routine sections…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There already is an answer on how to solve your script, but let me show you what's really happening:

```
@ ECHO OFF    : this is executed
SETLOCAL      : this is executed
CLS           : this is executed

:HELLO        : this is read
ECHO Hello    : this is executed

:BANANAS      : this is read
ECHO Bananas! : this is executed

:WORLD        : this is read
ECHO World!   : this is executed
GOTO:EOF      : this is executed: your script goes to EOF and finishes.

CALL HELLO    : this is not executed, as your script has gone to EOF.
CALL WORLD    : this is also not executed, as your script has gone to EOF.
```

Hence the result of the executions:

```
Hello
Bananas!
World!
```

Answer (score 3):

This is more like what you want.

A call will jump to the label, the GOTO:EOF will return to the call and continue.

The script will also just fallthrough any label, they are not functions like in bash.

Hope that explains it a bit.

```
@ ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
CLS

CALL :HELLO
CALL :WORLD
GOTO:EOF


:HELLO
ECHO Hello
GOTO:EOF

:BANANAS
ECHO Bananas!
GOTO:EOF

:WORLD
ECHO World!
GOTO:EOF
```